# Issue when executing a list of tasks, that have multiple async calls inside each one

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, task-parallel-library

I got this tentative piece of code below, that should generate a list of tasks to execute concurrently. The code inside the try...catch... is mean to represent each of those tasks. But the code block itself, contains 3 async calls that should execute sequentially, basically the 2nd call depends on the first and the third on the second.

```
var syncActions = new List<SyncAction<ContactDto>>();
ContactDto contactDto = null;

var syncActionTasks = updatedNodes.Select(async node =>
{
    SyncAction<IUmbracoActiveCampaignEntity> syncActionResult;
    contactDto = Mapper.Map<ContactDto>(node);

    try
    {
        var firstAsyncCallResult = await this.Contacts
            .GetByEmailAsync<ContactsRoot>(contactDto.Email);

        //...(code omittted for brevity)...

        var secondAsyncCallResult = await this.Contacts
            .AddOrUpdateAsync(firstAsyncCallResult);

        //...(code omittted for brevity)...

        var thirdAsyncCallResult = await this.Contacts
            .GetAccountContactAssociation(secondAsyncCallResult);

    }
    catch (ActiveCampaignException ex)
    {
        // handle error
    }

    return Task.FromResult(contactDto);
})
.ToList();

var result = await Task.WhenAll(syncActionTasks);

//...(code omittted for brevity)...
```

What I experience, is that the when the code executes the `firstAsyncCallResult`  instead of continuing down to the other 2 async calls, it jumps back to the beginning of the code 
`SyncAction<IUmbracoActiveCampaignEntity> syncActionResult;` and although all the code runs "fine" the line `var result = await Task.WhenAll(syncActionTasks);` returns the right number of `contactDto` objects, but these objects themselves show up repeated, and not unique as expected.

Any clue, why and what could be adjusted to get the desired outcome? Any directions and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `contactDto`, `Mapper` and `this.Contacts` objects are thread-safe? Hopefully they are, because they are going to be accessed concurrently by multiple threads without synchronization. Also how is the variable `syncActions` related to the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3):

> What I experience, is that the when the code executes the firstAsyncCallResult instead of continuing down to the other 2 async calls, it jumps back to the beginning of the code `SyncAction<IUmbracoActiveCampaignEntity> syncActionResult;`

Yes, once the first `await` is hit, a `Task` is returned from the lambda and the next iteration will begin. Once the `Task` returned from `GetByEmailAsync` has completed, the method will resume.

Also `Task.FromResult` should not be used in an `async` method; `async` methods implicitly return a `Task`, so you do not need to create one yourself. Simply return the DTO:

```
return contactDto;
```

By using `Task.FromResult` the way you have, the lambda's return type is `Task<Task<ContactDto>>`.

The call to `ToList()` is also superfluous, as `Task.WhenAll` accepts `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` which is already returned from your `Select`.